# Are there any consistency proofs for propositional or first-order logic?

Tags: reference-request, logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

Take for example the Hilbert-style axiomatizations of the propositional and first-order calculus. Since a crucial point when operating with a proof system is that no contradictions must be found in it, it seems to me reasonable to look for a *consistency proof* of those calculus. But I googled it and I could not find anything about it.

So, my question is:

> *Is there a consistency proof for propositional and first-order logic?*

and if there is,

> *How is this proof carried out?*

the reason I ask this is because, since the tools for any proof is an logical apparatus itself, a consistency proof of a logical system X seems to assume that X is already consistent! Or this proof is carried out using second-order logic such like Gentzen's consistency proof of PA?

I appreciate if you shed some light into these topics or indicate some reference on the subject.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property you're looking for is generally a consequence of the logic being **sound**. The *soundness theorem* for a proof system states that everything it can prove (from a given theory) is true in every interpretation of the logical language (that satisfies each of the theory's axioms).

In particular, once you know a logic to be sound, you know it cannot prove both $\varphi$ and $\neg\varphi$, except from an inconsistent theory.

In particular, if you're considering the *empty theory* over some logical language, you can take the model with one element, where every relation symbol is always true. Then for any $\varphi$ you can think of it will be easy to find out whether it is true in this trivial model -- and depending on whether it is or not, either $\neg\varphi$ or $\varphi$ will be unprovable in the logic, because you know it doesn't prove anything that is false in any model.

Note that in order to speak of models *in general* you need some set theory, but if you specialize the semantics of the theory to the trivial model, you can express everything *without* needing sets. In addition, the soundness proof of the logic can usually be condensed down to a proof of "everything that can be proved from the empty theory is true about the trivial model" which *does not* depend on any infinitary set theory.

(This is in particular the case for the usual proof systems for propositional and first-order logic).